# Is it possible to detect part of a speech (noun, verb, Adjective...) using Azure's Text Analytics?

Tags: c#, azure, nlp

I'm working on Microsoft Azure's Text Analytics service. It works well in order to find sentiment and keyword extraction from a given unstructured text, but I'm more interested to find out part of speech from a given text. 
Is there any workaround or a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

check out Project Splat from Microsoft Research http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/msrsplat/

From the website

> Statistical Parsing and Linguistic Analysis Toolkit is a linguistic
>   analysis toolkit. Its main goal is to allow easy access to the
>   linguistic analysis tools produced by the Natural Language Processing
>   group at Microsoft Research. The tools include both traditional
>   linguistic analysis tools such as part-of-speech taggers and parsers,
>   and more recent developments, such as sentiment analysis (identifying
>   whether a particular of text has positive or negative sentiment
>   towards its focus)